# How to display default file extension icons in Xamarin viewcell or Grid or somewhere?

Tags: c#, file, xamarin

I'm trying to create Xamarin forms application, my app downloads some files from web server to mobile storage, so i can see files in file  explorer. Now I want to see them in my custom form. Is there any approach to display default file type icon, or i have add my own icons in project and match each extension with icons?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeWaA.png)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to associate a file extension with an icon automatically. You'll have to do it manually

Comment: Your question does not have enough  data to understand the issue please add some more things like for eg what have you already tried or some code

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform. On iOS and Android there is no such thing as file icon provided by the system, so you have to provide your own. On some other platforms it is possible to get file icon using the native APIs (UWP, WPF, macOS), but the implementation is different for each platform and you may use Dependency service to implement this.